# Color comparison tool

Tags: gratis, color

I've these two colors: `00BAFF` and `009FDA`. I'm looking for a tool to compare these two colors.

For instance I want to be able to know the way to pass from the first color to the second with color operations like: how much **darken** or **lighten**, how much **saturation**, how much **red**, **green**, **blue**, ...

- Can work only with RGB schema or HSL one's
- No platform restriction
- I'd prefer a gratis app

Comment: Do you have any [standard color distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) in mind?

Comment: I didn't know this concept @FranckDernoncourt. My aim is to use these calculated distance values with Less's color functions. So it could be related with their implementation...

Comment: Converting the colors from RGB to HSL will give you exactly what you want: the difference in L tells you by how much to darken or lighten, S the difference in saturation and H the difference in hue (position on the color wheel).